# How to get public IP of instance in CloudFormation template when using LaunchConfig

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template with `LaunchConfig`. In `UserData` I need to reference public IP of the instance being created. I wanted to use `Fn::GetAtt`, but it requires logical name and I'm not sure how I can define it when using `LaunchConfig`.

```
"LaunchConfig": {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Metadata" : {"..."},
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId" : "...",
    "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
    "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
    "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "..."
    ]]}}
  }
},
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yes. As accepted answer explains, the way to do it is through [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) service

Comment: @arnaslu, did you have to reference the IP within the same resource, or in a different resource ? If in a difference resource, how did you "export" the value of the IP? Thanks

Comment: @TheRock3t I wanted to reference public IP in "UserData" script, so just internally. I think CloudFormation supports exporting PublicIP using "Fn::GetAtt", this should be fairly straightforward when you provision using "AWS::EC2::Instance", but not sure if it's possible using "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration". Keep in mind, that LaunchConfiguration can create multiple EC2 instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your UserData contains a shell script and all you need to do is reference the instance's own public IP within that script, you can get this value by querying the `public-ipv4` category of the [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) with `curl` or any other http utility:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to directly retrieve the Public IP address of an EC2 instance generated by an Auto Scaling group. The reason being that the EC2 instance is not managed by the CloudFormation template. The template has no knowledge of the EC2 instance.

There are a couple of workarounds though.

Option 1: Allocate and assign an Elastic IP address.

Rather than detecting the auto-assigned IP address, allocate an Elastic IP address and assign it into the User Data of your EC2 instance and have the EC2 instance assign it to itself via it's startup script.

It's next-to-simple to do if your Auto Scaling group is only creating a single EC2 instance. It can still be done with 2 or more EC2 instances, but you'll have to create a pool of Elastic IP addresses to pull from.

Option 2: Use a WaitCondition with custom data that includes your EC2 instance's IP address.

Create a WaitCondition that your CloudFormation template waits on. In your EC2 instance, have it retrieve it's own public IP address, then signal the WaitCondition when it's ready. Have it include the IP address inside the signal's "Data" field.

References: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html